# firefoxの拡張機能開発に関する簡単な質問

Tags: javascript, firefox

1. firefox 2018/12の最新版で拡張機能開発をしているのですが
   コンテンツスクリプトが出したxhrHTTPリクエストをwebページのjavascriptが検知したりxhrの要求先URLを取得することは可能でしょうか

   - またコンテンツスクリプトの変数にアクセスしてくることはあるのでしょうか。`XMLHttpRequest.onsend=function(){}`とかで情報ぬすむ
2. また、コンソールに表示されている内容(自分が適当にデベロッパーツールで`alert("unnko")`とか実行した履歴も含む)をwebページのjsが取得したりすることはできますか?
3. コンテンツスクリプトはwebページについてるjsと同じように動作しますが、webページについてるjsがコンテンツスクリプトの実行内容やソースコードを取得したりすることはできますか

Comment: 拡張機能のコンテンツスクリプトはwebページについてるjsと同じような感じで動作しますが

Comment: nekkeuさん回答していただけませんか??!!